# Best tutorial about the variational quantum eigensolver (VQE)

Tags: vqe, error-mitigation

I want to find a tutorial on VQE with a good valance between the theoretical background of the method, and it's working implementation on  QPU. Covering advanced topics such as quantum error mitigation.

Any advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best review of VQE that I have came across is the following:

[The Variational Quantum Eigensolver: a review of methods and best practices](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2111.05176.pdf)

Chapter 8 covers a good amount of material on error mitigation techniques. Furthermore, it has all the references you need to look up for more details.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Your proposal is a very complete methodological review. However, working implementation if the methods are missing, right?

Comment: yes, some of the methods are available through various open source codes, but some you need to write the code for yourself.